# Public key encryption with a large number of users

Tags: encryption, public-key, tls

I'm building an app that will primarily be iOS or Android based. My plan is for every user to have their own key pair. The public key will be stored on the server along with a 128 bit UUID which is used to identify each user. The private key will obviously stay on the device.

When a message is sent to other people the sending device queries the server for the public keys of all the recipients. It will then encrypt the message and send it to each user according to their public key and UUID.

First of all I would like to know if that is a reasonable solution? I'd encrypt the transport as well using TLS 1.3.

How much CPU does it take up to encrypt hundreds of messages every time someone sends a message from their device? If you are only talking talking to one person it is easy but what if there are one hundred or more talkers?

Since the clients are mobile phones they won't have the same CPU performance available to them and sending lots of messages to lots of receivers would eat up battery pretty quickly.

I'm still learning about the proper way to handle encryption so if I have made a silly mistake I'd appreciate being corrected.

Comment: I found the question vague; hundred or more?. what are the exact constraints of the client devices? What is your aim? solutions; encrypt the message with a random key then send key for the recipients with their public key so there is only one encryption. This is a common solutions among the group chats

Comment: You migth use https://doc.libsodium.org/

Comment: possible dupe of [Secure group chat with large groups](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/57760/18298) and [How to use symmetric encryption on 1on1 and group chat messenger?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/100104/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka Sorry for not being clear. I'm basically looking to create a secure group chat. I see you have provided a couple of links and they are really helpful.

Comment: https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1566/36960

Comment: @DannyNiu Thank you for the link. It was interesting.

Comment: Can we close this question as a dupe?